# Not able to perform GET request by calling the fetch method on an instance of HttpClient in Aurelia

Tags: fetch, aurelia, http-get

I am trying to GET request by calling the fetch method on an instance of HttpClient in Aurelia.

### app.html

```
<template>
   <button click.delegate = "getData()">GET</button>  
</template>
```

### app.js

```
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';

let client = new HttpClient();

export class App {

   getData() {
      httpClient.fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
         console.log(data);
      });
   }
 }
```

### main.js

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging()
    .plugin('aurelia-history-browser');


  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

I have also installed fetch **`bower install fetch`**

Now while running the application using **`http-server -o -c-1`**, I am encountering the below error

```
"GET /aurelia-history-browser" Error (404): "Not found"
```

What is that I am missing.

### Update

Finally I did, but no magic (missed import 'fetch';) It's not there in the [official document](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/fetch-client/latest/http-services/2).

```
import 'fetch';
import {HttpClient, json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';

let httpClient = new HttpClient();


export class App {

    constructor() { 

    this.UserRecords = this.fetchUserDataFromWebService();

    } 

    fetchUserDataFromWebService()
    {
          var serverData = "";


         httpClient.fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(data => {               
                 serverData = data;             
              });

              alert('Data Received from Server');         
          return serverData;
    }
}
```

Only one problem: if I don't use the **alert box**, then I am receiving the error **"Error: Value for 'UserRecords' is non-repeatable"** . How to solve this?

Comment: It would seem as though your question is a bit misleading. I assume if you comment out the line `.plugin('aurelia-history-browser')`, your error will go away, but I fail to see what the error has to do with the http client.

Comment: No, i did all those.But same error.Finally , i applied JQuery's ajax to get it done

Comment: So you don't fancy trying to figure out what you are doing wrong? Just go with jQuery instead?

Comment: But my requirement is not with JQuery but with fetch-client..i think i am almost done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer for the question in your answer, try this:

```
export class App {

    constructor() { 

    this.UserRecords = null;//.slice(0,5);
   this.fetchUserDataFromWebService();
    } 

    fetchUserDataFromWebService()
    {
         httpClient.fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(data => {               
                 this.UserRecords = data;             
              });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did..but no magic (missed import 'fetch';) It's not there in the [official document](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/fetch-client/latest/http-services/2)

```
import 'fetch';
import {HttpClient, json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';

let httpClient = new HttpClient();


export class App {

    constructor() { 

    this.UserRecords = this.fetchUserDataFromWebService();//.slice(0,5);

    } 

    fetchUserDataFromWebService()
    {
          var serverData = "";


         httpClient.fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(data => {               
                 serverData = data;             
              });

              alert('Data Received from Server');         
          return serverData;
    }
}
```

Only one problem... if I don't use the **alert box**, then I am receiving the error **"Error: Value for 'UserRecords' is non-repeatable"** . How to solve this?